# A more accurate method to solve hyperbolic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hi all,

I have a set of hyperbolic PDE and I have been solving this equation uisng Lax-Wendroff method (from Richtmyer). The solution is OK while I am looking for a better approach to do it. Is there a method of third or fourth order accuracy? Thanks.

And BTW, this is a 1-D problem.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "Lax-Wendroff fourth order" yielded the following paper:

G. Zwas and S. Abarbanel, [Third and Fourth Order Accurate Schemes for Hyperbolic Equations of Conservation Law Form](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2004918), Mathematics of Computation Vol. 25, No. 114, Apr., 1971, 229-236.

It contains explicit formulas.